# Add background and font colour to a button with material design

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to design a login form with a material design on Qt which should look something like this:

[image]

However I can't figure out how to add colour to the button in QML and change the font colour of the button text. This is what I have got so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    property alias login: login

    Pane {
        id: pane
        x: 144
        y: 117
        width: 353
        height: 246
        clip: false
        font.strikeout: false
        background: Rectangle {
                color: "#ffffff"
            }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            x: 139
            y: -158
            anchors.fill: parent

            TextField {
                id: username
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("Username")
            }

            TextField {
                id: password
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("Password")
            }

            Button {
                id: login
                text: qsTr("Login")
                spacing: -2
                font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                highlighted: false
//                background: Rectangle {
//                            implicitWidth: 100
//                            implicitHeight: 40
//                            color: button.down ? "#d6d6d6" : "#f6f6f6"
//                            border.color: "#26282a"
//                            border.width: 1
//                            radius: 4

//                        }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see (in the commented code) I tried to add colour using `Rectangle` with the `background` property but this removes the button features like shadow, `highlight`, darken on click and so on. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

For reference here is the output of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a design that complies with the *Google Materials* design guidelines, the easiest way, is to use

```
QtQuick.Controls.Materials
```

To use them, it is sufficent to use any of the methods described [**here**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls-2) to *activate* them in your application. To try it out, I'd reccomend the *command line argument*. Just start your application with

```
-style material
```

If you want to have it fixed in your code, put it in the `main.cpp`:

```
QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");
```

Note that the `-style` options is the very same option defined [**here**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) for widgets and [desktop os styles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#details). Despite this quick styles and widget styles are *totally different things* and you cannot apply the former to the latter and vice versa. Widget

---

**If now you already use** the `Material`-style, but are not contempt with it and desire to change some of the definitions for selected controls, you can import

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Materials 2.x
```

where you need to adapt `x` to the most recent version installed. `0` is the right one for `Qt5.7`

Then you can alter specific aspects like

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: login
        text: qsTr("LOGIN")
        Material.background: Material.Orange // Change the background
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use the `Material` and only want to change a specific color of the Control you need to understand why it is not that easy to do, without messing it up.

> I tried to add colour using Rectangle with the background property but this removes the button features like shadow, highlight, darken on click and so on. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

You can't just change the color of the `background`, as there is not **the color**. There are various colors that are applied for different states. The expression might look like this:

```
color: (control.down ? 'darkgrey' : 'lightgrey')
```

So if you change the `color` to `orange` like this:

```
color: 'orange'
```

you messed up, as now the other state is not considered anymore.

Additionally, of course, you can't change the color of the `background` like `background.color: 'green'` from the beginning, as QML does not know about the property `background.color`. It expects an `Item` there, which has no `color` and the `Rectangle` is only created later. So what you need to do is

1. Be cautious to not override states
2. Wait until the property is available

*example.qml*

```
Button {
    id: login
    text: qsTr("LOGIN")

    Binding {
        target: login
        property: "background.color"
        value: 'red'
        when: !login.pressed // Here comes the state
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to add this style if not already present to my Qt? I tried  `-style Material` it gave me an error maybe because it is not installed? `-style Windows` works fine on Qt in an Ubuntu machine

Comment: `-style material` is for QML/QtQuick.Controls 2.x. I have not seen any reference that there is an *official* QtWidget style called material. You might try to find third-party implementations [like this one](https://github.com/martinrotter/qt-material-stylesheet) though. I don't know neither the state of this project, nor the quality but it might be worth a try?

Comment: How do I add this to my project? Do I have to go into installation directory and make changes?? @derM

Comment: As I don't use QtWidgets I can only guess blindly. The base of my guess are those: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop - My guess is, to use `yourQApplication.setStyleSheet("path/to/stylesheet")` in your `main.cpp`

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal as said styles are totally different things between widgets and quick. So no, you can't use material. Actually, you can only use the styles shipped with your version of Qt (e.g. windows style or fusion on Win, gtk style or fusion on a linux spin and so on). That said you can style controls on your own or use stylesheets. The latter are waaay easier, especially if you have not much experience with Qt BUT are also painfully slow. The former are all the way around. I think we are going out of topic here, you should research a little bit about this stuff or post another question.

Comment: Ah well, I just read about the "windows working in ubuntu"...maybe they have changed policies about styles distribution. The rest of my comment still holds. \O_O/

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo yeah very true. The thing is I have already designed some part of my project(frontend and backend) using Qt Widgets and was looking for an easier way to simply improve the look using Material design. Now I have to redo all of it using Quick , not to mention the integration of quick with c++ for the backend which is an entire month of work altogether.

Comment: If everything is working fine I don't think is worth the effort. Elevation can be a little bit tricky but you should obtain a decent looking GUI if you work your way inside style(sheet). Up to you, obviously. No one knows the requirements as well as you.

Comment: But isn't Qt Quick a better option for designing like going forward? I am very new to Qt and seeing the recent shift towards QML  and Quick from Widgets, I felt maybe I should redesign for a better user experience. Should I stick with Widgets and use stylesheets instead?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Can we have a quick chat over this? have sent an invite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149862/discussion-between-bacarozzo-and-abhishek-agarwal).

Answer (score 3):

In order to theme a Material controls, you have to use the [Material attached properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#attached-properties)

In your case you want to use [`Material.background`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-background-attached-prop) :

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
// ...
Button {
    id: login
    text: qsTr("Login")
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Material.background: Material.Indigo
    Material.foreground: "white"
}
```

Note that buttons should have upercased text, according to the [material guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply [`highlight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-button.html#highlighted-prop) a `Button` to make the button colorize its background in a style-independent way. The Material style fills the background with the accent color and makes the text light:

```
Button {
    text: qsTr("Login")
    highlighted: true
}
```

A highlighted `Button` is by far more efficient than a customized button. Customization should be done only if necessary. It is just a visual highlight. There can be multiple highlighted buttons. Highlighting a `Button` does not affect focus.